# Available open data on Portuguese Soccer League

Tags: data-request, sports, football

Is anyone aware of open data involving the Portuguese soccer league (Primeira Liga)?

Answer (score 1):

For soccer players, Kaggle hosts the **[FIFA 18 Complete Player Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/thec03u5/fifa-18-demo-player-dataset)**. Accessing the data requires registration.

> 17k+ players, 70+ attributes extracted from the latest edition of FIFA

To build a dataset for just the Portuguese soccer league, you would have to download CompleteDataset.csv and build a filter on "Club" for the clubs that are in the target league. Then you have the complete stats for those players.

[image]

*([related answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13255/1511))*

Answer (score 1):

There are results from the Primeira Liga as well as many other leagues (mostly from Europe) here: http://www.football-data.co.uk/portugalm.php

Goals, results, odds, etc.